# How can I Set iMacros to run Randomly?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, imacros

This is my code :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:check1 CONTENT=YES       
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:check8 CONTENT=YES       
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:check14 CONTENT=YES      
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:check19 CONTENT=YES      
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:t_score CONTENT=%0.75                      
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Submit<SP>Number
```

I want to set line 1 to run Randomly,for example it differs from **check1** to **check6**
And in line 2 it differs from **check7** to **check12**
And in line 3 it differs from **check13** to **check17**
And in line 4 it differs from **check18** to **check21**
And in line 5 Number differs from **0.75** to **1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to generate random numbers, I think:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("Math.random() > 0.5 ? : 'check1' : 'check6'")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:{{!VAR1}} CONTENT=YES
```

The `EVAL` function allows you to call JavaScript and perform arbitrary calculations. `Math.random()` generates a random number between 0 and 1, so 50% of the time we select `check1`, 50% of the time `check6`.

Furthermore, if the actual requirement is to generate labels between `min` and `max`, this alternative could work ([adapted from here](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL#Generate_a_random_number_within_a_specific_range)):

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var min = 1; var max = 6;
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                'check' + randomNumber;")
```

Tweak the `min` and `max` for your various examples. For the percentage option, you could try:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var min = 75; var max = 100;
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                '%' + randomNumber / 100.0;")
```

This generates a random number between 75 and 100, then divides by 100.0 to convert it into a percentage. If you want three significant digits, then 750, 1000 and 1000.0 can be used, etc.

(Note you may need to do the above all in one line - I've split it just to be easier to read)

Comment: If I want to select from check 1 to check 6 what should I do? For example check 2 or check 3...

Comment: OK, even more detail added!

Comment: Thanks a lot it was usefull